# Calling a lua function with it's address in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I've been wondering if it would be possible to call a lua function in C/C++ by using it's address.
For instance,

```lua
function print2(arg)
print("Printed: "..arg)
end

print(print2) -- prints what seems like a 64 bit address.
```

I am not very experienced with C nor the inner workings of the lua language, so sorry if this is completely out of the question.

Comment: Why would you want this? Call by name  [looks easier](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/cs420/lecture/LuaLectures/LuaAndC.html)

Comment: I've just been wondering if it was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Three reasons why:

1. [The documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_topointer) says "There is no way to convert the pointer back to its original value."
2. Light C functions, C closures, and Lua functions have different internal representations, but all just look like `function: 0x55664ffe8de0` when printed.
3. Even if you used some nonpublic function to get past point 1, and knew what kind of function it was to get past point 2, you still have the problem that the garbage collector could collect the function you want to call between when you get the pointer and when you call it.